# Top color of a Scene2d.ui window?

Tags: libgdx

I want to create a UI window in libgdx where the top part (the part containing the title and which allows you to drag the window) has a different background color from the rest of the window. I can only set the background color for the entire window, is it possible to change it for just this top part?

Code so far:

```
    WindowStyle windowStyle = new WindowStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.WHITE, skin.newDrawable("white", Color.BLACK));

    Window window = new Window("test", windowStyle);
    window.setMovable(true);
    window.padTop(20);

    stage.addActor(window);
    window.setPosition(100, 100);
    window.setSize(500, 300);
```

Comment: The window is treated as a single ninepatch. You could change the texture directly instead but to have two different colors during runtime would require your own Window widget.

Comment: @Jyro117 Thanks for the info. I'm not so familiar ninepatch. With changing the texture directly you mean that I would include the top color in the image file it's based on?

Comment: That is correct, you would just be changing the image file. Ninepatch is just a name for a texture you split into 9 sub parts and stretch them to fit whichever shape you want.

Comment: @Jyro117 Ok thanks, I trust this is the way to do it. Put your comment as an answer if you want and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The top bar for UI Windows in libgdx uses the same texture as the whole window. In order to change the color for the top bar the underlying texture file will need to be modified. libgdx treats it as a whole and there is no built-in way to specify separate colors for each component of a window.

There are other ways, but they are non-trivial and requires writing your own widget class to replicate most of the behavior of the built-in Window class.